# Use services in Loopback 4

Tags: typescript, loopback4

**In Abstract**

How to use `Loopback 4` service generator and create local service class to handle data outside the `*.repository` or `*.controller`

**In Detail**

I'm developing a system that requires external APIs to fetch data, complex hashing/encryption etc. that does not fall into controller scope or repository scope (for the sake of clean code). Loopback 4 has CLI command `lb4 service` to generate `service` and this is poorly documented. How to create a class inside the `/service` folder and import (or inject or bind or whatever) and use it's methods as we do with repositories?

**ex:**

call methods from service like `this.PasswordService.encrypt('some text')`
**or**
`this.TwitterApiService.getTweets()` that are defined in `/service` directory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out myself. I'll explain this in steps that I followed.

1. create folder `/src/service` and inside it create `myService.service.ts` and `index.ts` as same as in `controller`,`repository` etc. (or use `lb4 service` and select `local service class`). note: If you want to implement interface, you can.
2. Create binding key with`BindingKey.create()` method.

```
export const MY_SERVICE = BindingKey.create<ServiceClass>('service.MyService');
```

`ServiceClass` can be either class or interface.

3. Goto `application.ts` and bind the key (here *service.MyService*) to the service class.

```
export class NoboBackend extends BootMixin(
  ServiceMixin(RepositoryMixin(RestApplication)),
) {
  constructor(options: ApplicationConfig = {}) {
    super(options);
    ...

    //add below line
    this.bind('service.MyService').toClass(ServiceClass);

    //and code goes on...
    ...
}
```

4. Inject the service to the class you want. Here I inject to a controller

```
export class PingdController {
  constructor(
    @inject(MY_SERVICE ) private myService: ServiceClass,
  ) {}
  ...
  ...
}
```

Now you can access your service like `this.myService.getData(someInput)`...!!!

Comment: As a service can also have @config options in the constructor, is it possible to change the config params for each request and how? Thank you